# Dump all query results in file inside a plsql block

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am facing the following issue. I want to execute a query and export all the results in a file. My query is saved as in varchar2 type and i can execute immediate on it and give me all the results. Now these results how can i dump them all in a file. I don't want to select specific column names from the query or anything. It is like a bulk collect of many results and dump them to a file. Here is some pseudocode of what i was working on:

This is 1 way that is not going to work

```
Declare
filehandle1 UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
myquery     varchar2(4000) := 'Select column1'||'~'||'Column2'||'~'||' from mytable';
Begin
filehandle1 := UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('MYDIR','mydata','W');
    FOR emp IN (execute immediate (myquery)) LOOP --This part of course is not working
        UTL_FILE.PUT (filehandle1, emp.*);        --i dont want to write each column
    END LOOP;                                     --i have the columns and formatting ready of the query
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (filehandle1);
End;
```

This is another way again that will not work

```
Declare
    filehandle1 UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    myquery     varchar2(4000) := 'Select column1'||'~'||'Column2'||'~'||' from mytable';
    Begin
    filehandle1 := UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('MYDIR','mydata','W');
    UTL_FILE.PUT (filehandle1, myquery); --i want just to execute the query and write 
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (filehandle1);       --everything in the file
    End;
```

How can i just get everything and throw them in the file? Also i this has to be done in a plsql block therefore i cannot spool them Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your query concatenating all the columns into a single string? At the moment the concatenation you've showed is just making the query invalid but I guess that's pseudocode; hard to be sure what your really query (and result) will look like.

Comment: Yes it is concatenating all the results into a single string. I want my results to be st like dfg~jjjjjj~67237~jlhn

Comment: the reason i need these kind of results is that i want to append all values in a file with a delimiter in between and then i will use this file to load it with sqlloader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop over a cursor:

```
declare
  filehandle1 utl_file.file_type;
  myquery varchar2(4000) := 'select column1 ||''~''|| column2 from mytable';
  mycursor sys_refcursor;
  myresult varchar2(4000);
begin
  filehandle1 := utl_file.fopen ('D42', 'mydata', 'w');
  open mycursor for myquery; 
  loop
    fetch mycursor into myresult;
    exit when mycursor%notfound;
    utl_file.put_line(filehandle1, myresult);
  end loop;
  close mycursor;
  utl_file.fclose(filehandle1);
end;
/
```

Or more simply if you don't need the query to be a string (I'm not sure if you're actually getting it from another table, for example, otherwise I'm not sure why you'd have it as a `varchar2` variable):

```
declare
  filehandle1 utl_file.file_type;
begin
  filehandle1 := utl_file.fopen ('D42', 'mydata', 'w');
  for myrec in (select column1 ||'~'|| column2 as result from mytable)
  loop
    utl_file.put_line(filehandle1, myrec.result);
  end loop;
  utl_file.fclose(filehandle1);
end;
/
```

If I create and populate the table as:

```
create table mytable (column1 number, column2 varchar2(10));
insert into mytable (column1, column2) values (1, 'First');
insert into mytable (column1, column2) values (2, 'Second');
```

Then with either of those, the `mydata` file contains:

```
1~First
2~Second
```

If you want to explicitly use bulk collect you can do this:

```
declare
  filehandle1 utl_file.file_type;
  myquery varchar2(4000) := 'select column1 ||''~''|| column2 from mytable';
  mycursor sys_refcursor;
  myresults sys.odcivarchar2list;
begin
  filehandle1 := utl_file.fopen ('D42', 'mydata', 'w');
  open mycursor for myquery; 
  loop
    fetch mycursor bulk collect into myresults limit 100;
    for idx in myresults.first..myresults.last loop
      utl_file.put_line(filehandle1, myresults(idx));
    end loop;
    exit when mycursor%notfound;
  end loop;
  close mycursor;
  utl_file.fclose(filehandle1);
end;
/
```

Comment: something that i thought now but i don't know if it is possible to do: Can i declare a clob variable and then execute immediate the query BULK COLLECT INTO the clob and then utl_file.put_line(filehandle, the clob variable) Is it possible for this to be done?

Comment: Also can i ask you something Alex. For the sqlloader to process this file. Is it going to be any problem if at the end of evryline there is a new line or should the data be appended all in a huge pile in the file without new lines?

Comment: You can't bulk collect multiple results into a single `clob`, no. At some point you have to iterate over the rows returned by the query - whether that's writing them straight to a file as I've done, or to put them into a clob (and then write that... but why is that better?); or bulk collect into a collection and iterate over that to write them out, but again not sure that gains you much?

Comment: Depends how you write the control file - if you are creating that then having new lines would be more managable I'd have thought, and your data isn't current fixed-length records (you'd need to pad everything)  so you have to have new lines really. Kind of curious why you aren't using data pump for this though.

Comment: The first answer you gave me will work. The reason why the second answer cannot apply is that the query i have is not constant. I have for example 10 tables which i need to get the results and i have a loop which returns the column names for each table which are stored in a collection and then i am building the string of the query accordingly. Like for the first item in the collection it will be select col1,col2 from table1 and for the second item will be select select col1,col2,col3 from table2. Unless if its possible to have an execute immediate inside the for in parenthesis

Comment: @GeorgeGeorgiou - OK; it isn't possible, no. I've added an explicit `bulk collect` option in case you're working with a lot of data and want to find an optimal limit value, just as a variation. If you're querying every column from the table then I'm really not sure why you're doing it like this and not just exporting the table, either with `exdp` or the data pump API.

Comment: Thank you so much Alex for your help i really appreciate it. The reason i am not using data pump is that maybe there is a change in the way regarding the exported results therefore having plsql and iterating the column i might change things on the way

Comment: @Alex.. On 1 of the tables that i am exporting the data, it is giving me oracle ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: Bulk Bind: Truncated Bind. I searched for this error but what i found was that i am binding the results into a different format. But this doesn't make sense since as you explained me before.. using myresults sys.odcivarchar2list; i mix the string of the results into a varchar2 list.. Do you have any idea what is this causing it to happen? Also i have added an If myresult.count>0 then loop otherwise when the cursor didn't have results the for loop was crashing

Comment: @GeorgeGeorgiou - yes, or make it `for idx in 1..myresults.count loop`. Does the failing export have a `clob` field, or is the concatenated string > 4k? If so you'll need to rethink; if not `clob` then you could select into two variables (each < 4k) and write them both out, but dealing with a `clob` would be rather more complicated. Otherwise... not sure, you might need to ask a new question with the specifics of the failure.

Comment: @Alex.. yes alex you are right.. My table does have a clob column.. Then i will have to process the table separately to get the results in CLOB variable? What is your opinion?

Comment: @GeorgeGeorgiou - yes, you need to write the `clob` out in chunks (there are examples on this site), so you'd have to select that column on its own rather than as part of the concatenation. So yes, special handling. You may have to do something special with it in SQL*Loader too though - see [here for example](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/load-lob-data-using-sql-loader.php).

Comment: I'm getting an `ORA-00932 inconsistent datatypes: expected - got - ` at line `fetch mycursor bulk collect into myresults limit 100;` how can I fix this ?

Comment: @AlirezaSoori - you should ask a new question really, showing what you are doing and the error. You can refer back to this question if it's relevant, but there seems to be something you're doing differently and comments aren't really the place to figure that out.